# I cannot adjust brightness of my laptop HP g4 1351tx

Tags: drivers, brightness

I cannot adjust brightness of my laptop HP g4 1351tx. My `lshw -c display` output.

```
   *-display UNCLAIMED     
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GF119M [GeForce 610M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128)
   *-display UNCLAIMED
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:d1000000-d13fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

There must be something wrong with my driver. Because the nvidia display card and intel display card are both `UNCLAIMED`

I've searched for a long time and tried a lot of methods to fix it. For example, I modified the `/etc/default/grub` file, and also added a `/usr/share/X11/20-intel.conf` and a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, but none worked. And my `/sys/class/backlight` directory is empty.

I've also tried to reinstall the nvidia driver, after that I can login, but there was just a wallpaper left on the desktop and I cannot get any response by mouse click or keyboard. Finally I reinstalled Ubuntu. Maybe I have chosen the wrong driver?

Now I use the Nouveau display driver from `xserver-org-video-nouveau` and still cannot adjust the brightness. Any answer may help me.

Comment: What driver did you use? Have you used bumblebee?

Comment: I did't use the bumblebee but I've fixed it yesterday.  Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it yesterday.
I just changed the driver version to **Nvidia binary driver 331.113** by KDE system control panel.

By the way, I uninstalled the gnome desktop and installed the KDE instead.
The driver I selected doesn't work on gnome desktop, but works fine on KDE, I don't know why.

And after that I found that my nvidia display card was **claimed** while the Intel display card was still **unclaimed**. However, the brightness still couldn't be adjusted.

I kept searching for that and finally removed the boot parameter **"nosplash nomodeset"**.
I added the parameter when I installed the ubuntu and without it ubuntu couldn't boot.

Since I've changed the open source driver to the nvidia closed source  driver and my desktop environment runs smoothly.

**There's no need to adding the parameter so I removed it.**

In some way, the parameter **must be removed** once I selected the **correct driver** so that the Intel display card can be claimed.

That means, if I don't select the **correct driver** and my display cards are **unclaimed**, I must use the parameter **"nosplash nomodeset"** to make ubuntu boot normally.